# How to fix a corrupted SRT file

Tags: file-corruption

I was working on this srt file sudddenly my pc got shutdown I'm pretty sure i've saved the file at some point. now when I open the file it's just a blank file with no content in it yet file file size is still the same as the original file

When opening the file in a srt special program I get different type of errors

When opening the file using a text editor I get a content which is 1 line and 95,000 columns

[image]

Is there is a way to recover my file or atleast part of it?

[This is the file](https://filedoge.com/download/abb3f7cd5428c99fc43dc62111a3da6c8fc735c5f61690ebb107f675bdc9d2d90f9a65e100c43967418e)

Comment: The file from the link contains 95130 null bytes and nothing more.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski So no possible solution?

Comment: Maybe with `strings` reading from the block device or from a copy of it (a case somewhat similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/q/1701131/432690)), but *certainly not* with anything reading from the file you posted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device) This is our canonical question and the method with `strings` is now there as one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do when repairing whatever type of file is opening the file in a hex editor. Goal is to determine if the file contains any data in the first place.

It doesn't matter whether it's a MP4, a JPEG, a DOCX file, running some repair tool against an empty file makes no sense what-so-ever. Most of these tools wil give some kind of error message or say repair failed rather than just plain tell you, this file is empty, so you go try another tool, and another...

Anyway ..

I downloaded your file from the shady website (Chrome screams DANGER) and, this file can not be repaired as at contains nothing but zeros. It's an empty shell.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort much appreciated, btw I own the shady website I really have no idea why the chrome warning came to you sorry.

Comment: Chrome really gave me big red screen, see https://imgur.com/a/q5GJYu6. No need to apologize, Chrome can be wrong but as site owner you probably need to get the site reviewed if you rely on visitors.